# Django Model Formset ignore Form Instance on is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Formset made up by a Form where I exclude a required field that I want to fill programatically instead of asking the user to fill it.

My expectation is that I can exclude it from my `request.POST` dictionary, and add it with the line below, and that the `is_valid()` method will both use the `request.POST` data, and the initial data added to the instance passed to the form, to validate and save it.

`form_kwargs={"instance": MyModel(sale=5)}`

```
# My view.py
formset = self.get_formset(
    data=self.request.POST,
    form_kwargs={"instance": MyModel(sale=5)}
)
# Error here, 'sale' is not set.
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

The `get_formset()` method returns an instance of the formset.

```
# My formset factory method
def get_formset(self, **kwargs):
    MyFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(MyModel, form=MyForm)
    ...
    return MyFormSet(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Django will never use initial data in place of missing posted data - otherwise how could you ever use a form to set a field to empty? Instead, you should *exclude* that field from the form, in which case the existing instance value will be preserved.

Either do this explicitly in the Meta class of MyForm, or pass the `exclude` parameter to `modelformset_factory`.